# Integrate legacy database to a new Django app

Tags: django, database-migration, wagtail

I developed a new cms using django and wagtail.
**News website that I developed the CMS for, used to use a php cms storing data in a messy and not normalized mysql database.**

So now, I have to store all old database records in my new django app's database.
As the links to news in old cms were generated based on their ID and obviously the old links should keep pointing to the corresponding content, I have to keep IDs as well as other fields.

Right now I am confused about what approach should I take in order to do the job.
Basic idea is to use inspectdb generating a new model for records in old database, then write a script to fetch each object from old db, use it to generate an object of newly developed models and save the object in new database.
What more efficient approaches can I take?

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a project with the same problem.

**Inspectdb** worked well but I had to do a lot of cleaning on the modelos.py. You will also have to work out ManytoMany relationships if your database has any.